# Git: слияние мастера в готовую ветку

Tags: git

Будучи на ветке master я с помощью команды `git checkout -b feature/с1` создал новую ветку и автоматически переключился на неё. Но работа с этой веткой приостановилась и она стала морально устаревшей, но сегодня мне надо продолжить с ней работать. Для этого мне надо повторно смержить ветку master в ветку c1, чтобы она стала актуальной с данными "мастера". Я пробовал повторно выполнить команду `git checkout -b feature/с1` но гит сказал, что такая ветка есть. Я понимаю, что смерджить легко, я не помню последовательность, что - куда?

Мне надо стоять на ветке мастер и мерджить с1 или наоборот, стоять на ветке с1 и мерджить?

```
 (m1)-----(m2)---------------------------------(m3)
            \                                   /
    создал новую ветку            надо (m3) смаржить в (с1)
             \                                /
            (c1)                            (с1)
```

Comment: Back merge --- плохая практика. Лучше что-то типа `git pull --rebase origin master`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Я пробовал повторно выполнить команду `git checkout -b feature/с1` но гит сказал, что такая ветка есть.

У вас указан лишний параметр `-b`. Он отвечает за создание ветви перед переключением.

> я не помню последовательность, что - куда?

`git merge` вливает указанную ветку в текущую.

т.е. последовательность действий такая:

1. checkout на ветку, в которую.
2. merge ветки из которой взять изменения.

> Для этого мне надо повторно смержить ветку master в ветку c1

Соответственно checkout на c1 и merge master

Comment: Да, я это знаю. мне важно знать при мердже "что" и "куда" мерджится. т.е. где должен быть указатель? Я немного почитал, и всё сводится к тому, что мне надо перейти на сетку "с1", и оттуда выполнить команду `git merge master` верно? или наоборот будучи на ветке мастер, выполнить команду `git merge c1` ?

Comment: @Igor-Potapov советую для старта понимания гита и команд потратить полдня и пройти [этот курс](https://stepik.org/course/3145) на степике.

Comment: @Igor-Potapov, дополнил ответ